how to align circle between two circles diaogonally

im trying to put a circle beween these two shapes, exactly where the blue is i want to put a circle, but it got to align to both cirles so i can make a shape with shape builder tool.
im very tired if it makes little sense

Okay, so illustrator has no snapping that does this but that is okay. There are few ways to solve this. I'm going to outline the easiest one of them.
Say you know the size of the circle that you want align perfectly. Since yours is close this would work fine.
Take the two other circles and choose Object → Path → Offset Path and offset the circles the radius (half diameter) of your adjoining circle. The center of the circle now lies on the intersection of the two offset lines.


I would like to note that illustrator is a terrible CAD application  (although technically it is one, being that CAD stands for computer-aided design which illustrator is certainly doing)
